# Synaptics touchpad not working suddenly

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics, input-devices

My touchpad has been working until suddenly it stopped detecting input, or button clicks. If I run `lsinput`, I see that it is in fact detected.

(`/dev/input/event6
   bustype : BUS_I8042
   vendor  : 0x2
   product : 0x7
   version : 433
   name    : "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
   phys    : "isa0060/serio1/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_ABS`)

If I go into mouse settings, there is only my USB mouse there, no touchpad. I don't want to use my laptop with only a USB mouse. Help?

EDIT: Touchpad settings DO appear in mouse settings. They weren't there last time I checked. Interesting.

(Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

solved problem for me. It seems that with frequent updates something was colliding.